# Calculate time in Android

Tags: java, android

I am very confused about calculation of time. I would like to set up 2 variables:

1. Current time (for example 8:00:00)
2. Current Time multiple by what? to get 8:00:05)(Lets say FutureTime).

and Finally to check that if the current time is not greater than FutureTime will do in a process

for example :

```
if(currentTime <= FutureTime)
{
     do something
}
```

quiz program

Can anyone recommend me how to do that?

Comment: take a look at JodaTime (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) - this will make your life easier (in FutureTime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for this kind of calculation it is always easy to use milisecond represnetation of the time. you can get the milis of current time using [System.currentTimeInMilis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) method. So using this you can compare two timestamps easily like other mathematical comparision

So from the current time you can easily get the future time by adding the milis of the interval .. lets the current time is `x` milis. so you can get the 5 second future time by `x+5*1000` milis

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to checking the time in a loop would be to run your task in a separate thread and interrupt it when needed - this would also be more flexible:

```
Runnable yourTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            //do something
        }
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(yourTask);               
t.start();

Runnable interruptingTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { t.interrupt(); }
};

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(interruptingTask, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can you explain me about the second last line (ScheduleExecutorService)?

Comment: It creates a ScheduledExecutorService with one thread - that service can run tasks in the future or at a certain rate (every x seconds for example). I use it to schedule the cancelling task 5 seconds in the future. You can have a look at the javadoc for more information.

Comment: THanks so much, Let me try out :)